BigQuery to Pandas Dataframe is super slow
When I run my app queries in BigQuery console, they take 3-4 seconds to return nearly a million rows.  The same queries in my streamlit python app (local, community cloud, GCP) all take about 180 seconds to complete including writing the results into a dataframe.  Upon instrumentation it shows most of the time is with rowiterator.  Is there a different way to do this?  Environments have plenty of RAM and CPU.
├─ 163.313 RowIterator._items_iter  google/api_core/page_iterator.py:206
│     [62 frames hidden]  google, requests, urllib3, http, sock...
│        88.930 _SSLSocket.read  <built-in>
├─ 8.598 QueryJob.__iter__  google/cloud/bigquery/job/query.py:2107
│     [27 frames hidden]  google, requests, urllib3, http, sock...
├─ 3.988 Row.__getitem__  google/cloud/bigquery/table.py:1501
│     [2 frames hidden]  google
├─ 3.569 Client.query  google/cloud/bigquery/client.py:3362
│     [25 frames hidden]  google, requests, urllib3, http, sock...
└─ 2.815 [self]  users.py

        bq_client = st.session_state.bq_client
        sql_query = f"""
                    SELECT *
                        FROM `dataexploration-193817.user_data.all_users_progress`
                    WHERE
                        first_open BETWEEN PARSE_DATE('%Y/%m/%d','{start_date}') AND CURRENT_DATE() 
                    """
        rows_raw = bq_client.query(sql_query)
        rows = [dict(row) for row in rows_raw]
        df_user_list = pd.DataFrame(rows)






I had a similar experience once, the solution I found was this built-in solution to_dataframe() that also uses pandas pkg directly from query result, it was way more faster than just loop though each row.
Here an example:
bq_client = st.session_state.bq_client
sql_query = f"""
    SELECT *
    FROM `dataexploration-193817.user_data.all_users_progress`
    WHERE first_open BETWEEN PARSE_DATE('%Y/%m/%d','{start_date}') AND CURRENT_DATE() 
"""
df_user_list = bq_client.query(sql_query).to_dataframe()


Thank you @dfop02.  This is a great  tip!  Although it didn't produce the order of magnitude improvement I hoped, it did improve overall by 12%.  Also note to use this you need:
pip install db-dtypes 

Something to keep in mind when comparing the latency of the cloud console to something else is that the console latency is really only exposing the time it took to execute the query and return the first page of results.
If you're comparing that to constructing a local dataframe that contains a million rows, there is likely a significant amount of data transfer to move the remaining rows after the first page.
Depending on your use case, something like BigQuery DataFrames may be a useful tool to defer that data movement until you've processed that dataframe further.

thanks for the reference to BigQuery DataFrames.  I did not know about that.  Yeah, once I instrumented the method I saw it was all in the serialization into the DF.  I will look into this library.
